Getting "Invalid token in authorization header" error while registering user with Hyperledger Fabric CA
I am trying to register and enroll users using Hyperledger Fabric CA in my Node.js application. However, I keep getting the following error when attempting to register a user:
2024/07/21 09:33:53 [DEBUG] Caller is using a x509 certificate
2024/07/21 09:33:53 [INFO] 172.18.0.1:41754 POST /api/v1/register 401 25 "Invalid token in authorization header: Failed to decode base64 encoded x509 cert: illegal base64 data at input byte 6"

The process involves creating a JWT-like authorization token using an admin's X.509 certificate and private key. This token is then used in the header of the registration request to the Fabric CA server. Despite following the documentation and examples, I am still facing issues with the authentication token. I suspect there is an issue with how I'm creating the authorization token. Here's the relevant part of my code:
const crypto = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const caURL = 'https://localhost:7054';
const caCertPath = '/path/to/ca-cert.pem';
const adminCertPath = '/path/to/admin-cert.pem';
const adminKeyPath = '/path/to/admin-key.pem';

async function getAdminCredentials() {
    const certificate = await fs.promises.readFile(adminCertPath, 'utf8');
    const privateKey = await fs.promises.readFile(adminKeyPath, 'utf8');
    return { certificate, privateKey };
}

function createAuthToken(cert, key, method, url, body) {
    const base64Cert = Buffer.from(cert).toString('base64');
    const base64Body = Buffer.from(body).toString('base64');
    const base64Url = Buffer.from(url).toString('base64');
    
    const payload = `${method}.${base64Url}.${base64Body}.${base64Cert}`;
    
    const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
    sign.update(payload);
    sign.end();
    const signature = sign.sign(key, 'base64');
    
    return `${base64Cert}.${signature}`;
}

async function registerUserWithCA(userId, role, affiliation) {
    const { certificate, privateKey } = await getAdminCredentials();

    const url = `${caURL}/api/v1/register`;
    const data = {
        id: userId,
        type: 'client',
        affiliation: affiliation,
        attrs: [
            { name: 'hf.Registrar.Roles', value: role },
            { name: 'hf.Registrar.Attributes', value: 'hf.Registrar.Roles, hf.Registrar.Attributes, hf.Revoker' }
        ]
    };

    const authToken = createAuthToken(certificate, privateKey, 'POST', url, JSON.stringify(data));
    const agentOptions = {
        ca: await fs.promises.readFile(caCertPath)
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, data, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
            },
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent(agentOptions)
        });

        return response.data.result.secret;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.response) {
            console.error(`Failed to register user: ${userId}`, error.response.data);
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to register user: ${userId}`, error.message);
        }
        throw error;
    }
}

// Example usage:
registerUserWithCA('testUser', 'client', 'org1.department1').catch(console.error);

